# Checkbox jquery - multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having troubles getting a checkbox change some HTML using JQuery.

I have a standard html checkbox with the following tags

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN1" class="checkbox Q1" value="AQN10" id="3mcq">
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN1" class="checkbox Q1" value="AQN11" id="3mcq">
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN1" class="checkbox Q1" value="AQN12" id="3mcq">
```

I am trying to then use JQuery to change some HTML based on the user ticking two correct options. I am using the value="" key to select which answers are right/ wrong

```
$(function () {

 ($('input[value=AQN12]:checked').val())) 

            $("input[name=AQN1]:checkbox").click(function () {

                    if ( $('input[value=AQN10]:checked').val() && $('input[value=AQN12]:checked').val() ) {
                            document.getElementById("CA1").innerHTML = "this is right";
                    } 

                    else {
                        document.getElementById("CA1").innerHTML = "this is wrong";
                    }
            });
        });
```

Below is an example of the checkbox function working with a just one condition met. ( AQN10)

```
$(function () {
            $("input[name=AQN1]:checkbox").click(function () {

                    if ($('input[value= AQN10]:checked').val()) {

                        document.getElementById("CA2").innerHTML = "this is right";
                    } 

                    else {
                        document.getElementById("CA2").innerHTML = "this is wrong";
                    }
            });
        });
```

I would like to try and get it so I can use the logical operators && or 'or' 
This way if the user selects one correct answer they would get a 'kind of correct!..' answer and when they select all the correct answers they get the full correct answer.

Thanks!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple checkboxes with the same id, Try to rename them like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN1" class="checkbox Q1" value="AQN10" id="3mcq">
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN1" class="checkbox Q1" value="AQN11" id="3mcq1">
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN1" class="checkbox Q1" value="AQN12" id="3mcq2">
```

now you can  reference like

```
$('input[value=AQN12]:checked').val())) 

            $("input[name=AQN1]:checkbox").click(function () {

                    if ( $('#3mcq1:checked').val() && $('#3mcq2:checked:checked').val() ) {
                            document.getElementById("CA1").innerHTML = "this is right";
                    } 

                    else {
                        document.getElementById("CA1").innerHTML = "this is wrong";
                    }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it makes sense now you've wrote it out, I will review my work later. I have put the other answer as correct as its put more context around it and helped me understand how I can approach the if else a little more clearly. Thank you all the same though

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `id` attribute should be unique for an element, this doesn't affect the functionality *(in this example)* but is good practice.

Then I would look at your element naming, as the checkboxes are separate, I would remove the `value` attribute and replace it with the `name`. This makes it more clear which checkbox you're targeting.

I've attached a snippet with these points in mind and hopefully provided a smoother work flow that is easy to understand

```js
$(function(){
  /* input that have type=checkbox and class=Q1 */
  $('input[type="checkbox"].Q1').click(function(){
    checkQ1();
  });
  
  function checkQ1(){
    /* store the checked state of each Q1 checkbox */
    var cb0_checked = $('input[name="AQN10"]').prop('checked'),
        cb1_checked = $('input[name="AQN11"]').prop('checked'),
        cb2_checked = $('input[name="AQN12"]').prop('checked');
    
    /* check if cb0 and cb2 are checked */
    if(cb0_checked && cb2_checked){
      $('#CA1').html('This is right');
      return;
    }
    
    /* NOTE: this will return "This is right" even if all 3 are checked - an alternative would be:
     * if(cb0_checked && cb2_checked && !cb1_checked){
    */
    
    /* check if either cb0 or cb2 are checked */
    if(cb0_checked || cb2_checked){
      $('#CA1').html('This is almost right');
      return;
    }
    
    /* neither are checked */
    $('#CA1').html('This is wrong');
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- You don't need this line - just including jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="AQN10" class="checkbox Q1"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN11" class="checkbox Q1"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="AQN12" class="checkbox Q1"><br>
<span id="CA1"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting it into context. I will use this method instead!..